# Fourier integral form of the delta function?

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm learning basic maths for physicist and was wondering what do we use the [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) for? What is the difference between "the Fourier integral form" and the usual way of expressing the delta function?

I know how to use it from elementary quantum mechanics classes so for instance $\delta _{ij}$ is equal to one if $i=j$ and zero if not.

Comment: To confirm, you are talking about the [Dirac delta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) $\delta(x-a)$? I ask because the example you provide is of the [Kronecker delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) $\delta_{ij}$.

Comment: Can you write the "usual way" of expressing the function that you're thinking of, as well as the Fourier integral form? I suspect this will help you and/or us.

Comment: hi sorry, what I have so far is $\delta(x)=\infty$ if $x=0$ or $0$ for $x\neq 0$, and that $\int\delta(x)dx=1$

Comment: I know how to use it when we are talking about wave functions in quantum mechanics but I'm not too sure about what you wrote above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question seems to confuse a number of things. Let me try to clear everything up:

1. There is a difference between the Kronecker delta $\delta_{ij}$ where $i,j$ are discrete indices, and the Dirac delta $\delta(x-y)$, where $x,y$ are continuous variables. Superficially, the latter can be thought of as the continuous version of the former. There is something of a similarity in the following expressions, which should clarify the relation between the two:
   \begin{align}
   \sum_if_{i}\delta_{ij}=f_j\hspace{1cm}&\Leftrightarrow\hspace{1cm}\int dx f(x)\delta(x-y)=f(y)\\
   \sum_{i}f_if_j\delta_{ij}=f_jf_j\hspace{1cm}&\Leftrightarrow\hspace{1cm}\int dx\ f(x)f(y)\delta(x-y)=f(y)f(y)
   \end{align}
2. If you know what the Fourier transform is, you'll know that its definition is (depending on your conventions, some factors of $\sqrt{2\pi}$ may or may not appear)
   $$\mathscr{F}(f(x))(k)=\int f(x)e^{-ikx}dx$$
   Moreover, you should know that 
   $$f(x)=\mathscr{F}^{-1}\bigl(\mathscr{F}(f(x))(k)\bigr)(x)$$
   Apply this identity to $\delta(x)$ and you'll find that the Dirac delta function (it's really a distribution!) can be written in a different way as well. That's all that's going on here, and the two ways of writing it are equivalent. The integral form is often just handy since it can be used to greatly simplify many integrals involving complex exponential functions.

Comment: Wow thank you ! I'm sorry but I'm not too sure what the difference is between the Kronecker and the dirac delta could you maybe just expand on that point? thank you !

Comment: That was going to be my next question! why do we get $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$! but you got there before me! its just definition by different people or for different situations>?

Comment: Okay so what does a continuous version of the former mean.. sorry its just I'm new to this..

Comment: This is a really good answer thank you very much I think i get it now ! :)

Comment: There is one last thing, every time I see the $\delta(x-y)$ I want to expand the bracket... is that not a thing we do?

Comment: Okay so I will refine my question

Comment: Why do we have a function of only $x$ suddenly turn into a function of $y$ on the far right hand side?

Comment: Oh I see So where $\psi=\psi(x,t)$ this is $\delta=\delta(x-y)$? Like a "function of"

Comment: Not really, since the Dirac delta 'function' is a distribution, so it really acts on functions (like the $f(x)$ in my examples). However, if you are only concerned with elementary applications, you can *pretend* like it's a function in the way that you just put it. If you want to understand what's going on more properly, consider reading appendix A of Mukhanov's book called **Introduction to Quantum Effects in Gravity**, available freely online (don't let the title deter you, the appendix isn't that hard).

Comment: Ok thank you a lot for your help! its much appreciated Danu :)

Comment: @Danu I think there's a small mistake in the fourier transform expression you've given. You meant to write $\mathscr{F}(f(x))(k)=\int f(x)e^{-ikx}dx$ right?

Comment: @Phonon good point. Edited ;) Feel free to correct it yourself next time you see something like this.

Comment: @Danu Alrighty ;)