# Ladder functions and operators - commutation and product

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, operators, commutator

I have been studying `An introduction to QFT by Peskin and Schroesder`, in my free time, to learn about the fascinating subject of QFT. I have a couple of basic questions related to the calculations, so I'll put them together:

**Q.1.** While going through some of the calculations related to Klein Gordon equation I see the following:
$$a_{p}e^{ip.x} + a_p^{\dagger}e^{-ip.x} = (a_{p} + a_{-p}^{\dagger})e^{ip.x} $$
How is $a_{p}^{\dagger}$ operating on $e^{-ip.x}$ equivalent to $a_{-p}^{\dagger}$ operating on $e^{ip.x}$?

**Q.2.** Now using the following 3 relations:
$$\phi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\omega_p}} (a_{p} + a_{-p}^{\dagger})e^{ip.x}$$
$$\pi(x) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}(-i) \sqrt{\frac{\omega_p}{2}} (a_{p} - a_{-p}^{\dagger})e^{ip.x}$$
$$[a_p, a_{p'}^{\dagger}] = (2\pi)^3\delta^{(3)}(p-p')$$
it is shown that:
$$[\phi(x), \pi(x')] = i\delta^{(3)}(x-x')$$
but all I could reach was:
$$[\phi(x), \pi(x')] = i\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} e^{ip.(x+x')}$$
Is the integral really the delta function somehow? Or (definitely) I have done the calculations wrong? I have checked multiple times to no avail.

Any help (hint or solution) is welcome.
*Unrelated info:* I was studying, earlier, using `Quantum Field Theory in a Nutshell By Zee` but finally left it because of extremely difficult mathematical problems one after another. I am hoping to get through this book more smoothly. Any other study material suggestions (in comments) are also welcome.

Comment: 1. $a_p$ does not operate on $\mathrm e^{ipx}$; the factors are just multiplied together. In any case, the identity you quote is false; it is true only under the integral sign (why?). 2. Yes, that integral is a Dirac delta (but $\delta(x+x')$ instead of $\delta(x-x')$, so you made a mistake somewhere).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform 1. yes, that was under integral sign only. <sorry, figured out the why part. Should have thought harder.> 2. oh! I will try to see where I did a mistake. Could you please elaborate a bit as to how that integral is dirac delta? Thank you for the help.

Comment: 1. Good. 2. See e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/334096/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133977/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/161902/84967, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600085/289977, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/488962/289977, etc.

Comment: After reading those links, I am kind of amazed that I never saw delta function in that context. If you would like to put the comment as an answer, I could use the green tick to close (sort of) this question or we can leave it like this.

Comment: You can answer your question yourself -- that would be a nice exercise for you, and users are encouraged to answer their own questions if they ever come up with a solution. Or you could just delete the post if you want to, no big deal. Whatever floats your boat.